# Confixx Login won't work after upgrade

Tags: debian, webserver

I have upgraded my confixx installation from 3.3.7 Pro to 3.3.8 and 3.3.9 Pro (Yes I'm little late - I know).

Now I have the problem that I can't login with my Accounts (Passwordreseted Accounts don't work too). I had turned Confixx in `$DEBUG=1`-Mode and see that the login on `login.php` is successfully, and get redirect to `/user/webXX/` and there the login is failed and to LoginForm is showed.

**access_log**:

```
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [20/Mar/2013:15:45:24 +0100] "POST /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302 170
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [20/Mar/2013:15:45:24 +0100] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 302
XX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [20/Mar/2013:15:45:24 +0100] "GET /user/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200
```

I'm using Debian 6.0.7

Anyone has an idea to get confixx work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some (unknown) reasons, the confixx update script has overriden my `/etc/apache2/confixx_mhost.conf`-file and so APC is active on my PHP 5.3 system for confixx.

To get the Login work again disable it for the Confixx VHost and add the following line into the file: `php_admin_value apc.enabled 0` after apache2 restarting the login works again.

I don't know why, but confixx has problem with $_SESSION when apc is enabled.